# При нажатии на мышь срабатывают сразу несколько событий из-за анимации (canvas игра)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Я уже задавал вопрос по этому проекту ([В какой-то момент, отскакивающий от краёв канваса мяч, попадает в баг и ведет себя аномально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997218/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%91%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%87-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5)), код тот же, только доработан.

В этой игре нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на пузырь он лопался, ну а при промахе - создавался новый. Вот только, видимо из-за огромной частоты requestAnimationFrame, нажатие мыши интерпретируется несколько раз и происходит одновременно оба события. Часть кода с условиями событий:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    for (let i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
    if(dotInObj(Mouse.x, Mouse.y, balls[i].xPos, balls[i].yPos, balls[i].ballSize)){
      balls.splice(i, i);
      pop.play();
    }
    else {
      createBuble(Mouse.x-ri(30, 50)/2, Mouse.y-ri(30, 50)/2);
      hah.play();
    }
  }
});
```

При нажатии на пузырь, он может либо просто лопнуть, при этом будет воспроизведено оба звука, либо то же самое, только на его месте появляется новый, хотя новые должны появляться только при нажатии на пустоту (не появляются).

Кроме того, иногда удаляются сразу 2, а то и 3 несвязанных с собой пузырей.
Что можно сделать?

Весь код:

```
function ri(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

function dotInObj (dotX, dotY, objX, objY, objSize) {
    if((dotX>objX&&dotY>objY)&&(dotX<objX+objSize&&dotY<objY+objSize)) return true;
  else return false;
}
//alert(ri(-10, 10)/10);

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var console = document.getElementById("console");
var speed = 1; // SPEED

var Mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

var hah = new Audio();
var pop = new Audio();
hah.src = "https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/combobreak-online-audio-converter_06FGwjv.mp3";
pop.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Blop-Mark_DiAngelo-79054334.mp3";
//hah.play();

cvs.onmousemove = function (event) { 
    Mouse = {
        x: event.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y: event.pageY - this.offsetTop
    }
    console.value = "X: "+Mouse.x+"Y: "+Mouse.y;
}

var balls = [];
balls.push(0);
function createBuble(XX, YY) {
    let ballSZ = ri(30, 50);
    balls.push({
      ballSize: ballSZ,
      xPos:         XX,
      yPos:         YY,
      xKof:         ri(1, 10)/10,
      yKof:         ri(1, 10)/10,
      ball:         new Image(),
    });
    balls[balls.length-1].ball.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/soap_bubbles/soap_bubbles_PNG37.png";
}

function iter(i) {
    //alert(i);
    createBuble(cvs.width/2, cvs.height/2);

    if (--i > 0) {
      setTimeout(function () { iter(i); }, 1000);
    }
}

iter(5);    

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
 for (let i=1; i<balls.length; i++) {
   ctx.drawImage(balls[i].ball, balls[i].xPos, balls[i].yPos, balls[i].ballSize, balls[i].ballSize);
   balls[i].xPos+=balls[i].xKof*speed;
   balls[i].yPos+=balls[i].yKof*speed;

   if (balls[i].yPos+balls[i].ballSize>=cvs.height||balls[i].yPos<=0) {
    balls[i].yKof += Math.random()/10;
    balls[i].yKof =  Math.abs(balls[i].yKof) * Math.sign(-balls[i].yPos);
   }

   if (balls[i].xPos+balls[i].ballSize>=cvs.width||balls[i].xPos<=0) {
    balls[i].xKof += Math.random()/10;
    balls[i].xKof =  Math.abs(balls[i].xKof) * Math.sign(-balls[i].xPos); 
   }
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(draw); 
 //console.value = "kek";
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    for (let i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
    if(dotInObj(Mouse.x, Mouse.y, balls[i].xPos, balls[i].yPos, balls[i].ballSize)){
      balls.splice(i, i);
      pop.play();
    }
    else {
      createBuble(Mouse.x-ri(30, 50)/2, Mouse.y-ri(30, 50)/2);
      hah.play();
    }
  }
});

balls[1].ball.onload = draw;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sazdan/60pqsLxv/267/

Comment: вообще не правильно делать проверки в цикле отрисовки, надо делать это через фиксированные шаги

Comment: это отдельный цикл при нажатии мыши

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм сначала должен проверить все пузыри в цикле не попали ли они под клик. А затем уже выйдя из цикла по условию создавать новый пузырь.

Удаление нескольких пузырей происходило из за того что вы использовали splice(i, i); а нужно splice(i, 1);

Переделал перебор от хвоста в начало, потому что при удалении хвост сдвигается и перебор в прямом направлении будет некорректным.

Вот исправленный кусок

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  t = true;
    for (let i=balls.length-1; i>0; i--) {
    if(dotInObj(Mouse.x, Mouse.y, balls[i].xPos, balls[i].yPos, balls[i].ballSize)){
      balls.splice(i, 1);
      pop.play();
      t = false;
    }
  }
  if (t==true) {
      createBuble(Mouse.x-ri(30, 50)/2, Mouse.y-ri(30, 50)/2);
      hah.play();
}
});
```

Если хотите чтобы пузыри удалялись по одному даже если под мышкой было несколько то вот

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  t = true;
    for (let i=balls.length-1; i>0; i--) {
    if(dotInObj(Mouse.x, Mouse.y, balls[i].xPos, balls[i].yPos, balls[i].ballSize)){
      balls.splice(i, 1);
      pop.play();
      t = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (t==true) {
      createBuble(Mouse.x-ri(30, 50)/2, Mouse.y-ri(30, 50)/2);
      hah.play();
}
});
```

Comment: Я подозреваю что могут быть баги из-за того что вы перебираете массив пузырей и в этом же цикле изменяете его длинну, если лопаете пузыри.

Comment: спасибо, а что можно сделать с тем, что оно сразу несколько пузырей лопает?

Comment: оно будто цепляет сразу 1-3 соседа в массиве, видимо тоже как-то связано с большой частотой

Comment: Всё из за того что splice(i, i); удаляет не 1 а i пузырей. Переписал ответ.