# Как избавиться постоянного инвертирования скорости?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Я написал код, **создающий круги по удержанию мыши**, притом эти круги *имеют рандомную скорость* и **при столкновении с границей экрана она инвертируется**.
Проблема в том, что *если круги спавнятся на границе экрана*, они могут передвигаться только "по" этой границе и за её пределы выйти не могут.
**Скорость постоянно инвертируется** и из-за этого они как бы стоят на месте по одной (или двум, если заспавнятся в углу) координатам, что с этим делать я не знаю.
*Даже как назвать этот баг я не знаю.*

Если не поняли, то просто *удерживайте мышь при x = 0 координате*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>.</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
 <canvas id="can" style="display: block"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getId(o) {return document.getElementById(o)};
  let can = getId('can'), ctx = can.getContext('2d'), rnd = (min, max) => Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min) + min,
  mouse = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   down: false
  },
  circles = [],
  Circle = class {
   constructor(position, radius, color, speed) {
    this.position = position,
    this.radius = radius,
    this.color = color,
    this.speed = speed
   }
  }, createCircle = (x, y, radius, color, speed) => circles.push( new Circle({x: x, y: y}, radius, color, speed) ),
  player = {
   position: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
   },
   radius: 20,
   color: "#0FF"
  };

  onresize = e => {
   can.width = innerWidth;
   can.height = innerHeight
  };
  can.style.background = "#000";
  onresize();

  document.onmousedown = e => mouse.down = true;
  document.onmouseup = () => mouse.down = false;
  document.onmousemove = e => {
   mouse.x = e.clientX;
   mouse.y = e.clientY
  };

  (loop = () => {
   ctx.fillStyle = "#0003";
   ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

   if(mouse.down) {
    createCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 20, "#FFF", {x: rnd(-10, 10), y: rnd(-10, 10)});
   };

   circles.forEach(circle => {
    let a = player.position.x - circle.position.x,
    b = player.position.y - circle.position.y,
    len = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);

    // Вот тут проблемы :|
    if(circle.position.x < circle.radius - circle.speed.x || circle.position.x > innerWidth - circle.radius - circle.speed.x) circle.speed.x = -circle.speed.x;
    if(circle.position.y < circle.radius - circle.speed.y || circle.position.y > innerHeight - circle.radius - circle.speed.y) circle.speed.y = -circle.speed.y;

    circle.position.x += circle.speed.x;
    circle.position.y += circle.speed.y;

    // Если расстояние (len) меньше суммы радиусов игрока и конкретного круга (если игрок коснулся круга), то цвет круга нужно изменить.
    circle.color = len < circle.radius + player.radius ? "#F00" : "#FFF";
    ctx.strokeStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.position.x, circle.position.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke()
   });

   player.position.x = mouse.x;
   player.position.y = mouse.y;

   ctx.strokeStyle = player.color;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.stroke();

   requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А зачем Вы удалили свой вопрос про круги? Я бы завтра возможно накидал пример ответа =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определяйте знак скорости абсолютно, а не инвертируйте его

Тут логика такая: берем знак положения шарика, если он отрицательный - значит нам нужно положительное направление. Все.

```
circle.speed.x = -Math.abs(circle.speed.x) * Math.sign(circle.position.x - circle.radius);
circle.speed.y = -Math.abs(circle.speed.y) * Math.sign(circle.position.y - circle.radius);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>.</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
 <canvas id="can" style="display: block"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getId(o) {return document.getElementById(o)};
  let can = getId('can'), 
        ctx = can.getContext('2d'), 
        rnd = (min, max) => Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min) + min,
  mouse = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   down: false
  },
  circles = [],
  Circle = class {
   constructor(position, radius, color, speed) {
    this.position = position,
    this.radius = radius,
    this.color = color,
    this.speed = speed
   }
  }, createCircle = (x, y, radius, color, speed) => circles.push( new Circle({x: x, y: y}, radius, color, speed) ),
  player = {
   position: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
   },
   radius: 20,
   color: "#0FF"
  };

  onresize = e => {
   can.width = innerWidth;
   can.height = innerHeight
  };
  can.style.background = "#000";
  onresize();

  document.onmousedown = e => mouse.down = true;
  document.onmouseup = () => mouse.down = false;
  document.onmousemove = e => {
   mouse.x = e.clientX;
   mouse.y = e.clientY
  };

  (loop = () => {
   ctx.fillStyle = "#0003";
   ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

   if(mouse.down) {
    createCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 20, "#FFF", {x: rnd(-10, 10), y: rnd(-10, 10)});
   };

   circles.forEach(circle => {
    let a = player.position.x - circle.position.x,
    b = player.position.y - circle.position.y,
    len = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);

    // Вот тут проблемы :|
    if (circle.position.x < circle.radius - circle.speed.x || 
           circle.position.x > innerWidth - circle.radius - circle.speed.x) 
              circle.speed.x = -Math.abs(circle.speed.x) * Math.sign(circle.position.x - circle.radius);
    if (circle.position.y < circle.radius - circle.speed.y || 
           circle.position.y > innerHeight - circle.radius - circle.speed.y) 
              circle.speed.y = -Math.abs(circle.speed.y) * Math.sign(circle.position.y - circle.radius);

    circle.position.x += circle.speed.x;
    circle.position.y += circle.speed.y;

    // Если расстояние (len) меньше суммы радиусов игрока и конкретного круга (если игрок коснулся круга), то цвет круга нужно изменить.
    circle.color = len < circle.radius + player.radius ? "#F00" : "#FFF";
    ctx.strokeStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.position.x, circle.position.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke()
   });

   player.position.x = mouse.x;
   player.position.y = mouse.y;

   ctx.strokeStyle = player.color;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.stroke();

   requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: [похожий  ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997241/188366)